# No sound in 13.04 on a TP X230

Tags: sound, 13.04, x230

All sound devices are correctly detected and modules loaded. Had a look at the community docuemntation and ran aplay -l in ther terminal and got this:

```
cookies@ThinkPad-X230:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
```

The hard drive is encrypted and so is my home folder. Any ideas?

SOLUTION: Ask Ubuntu is a bit...weird to put it nicely. A bit ridiculous but I found my answer, and since I can't post comments with proper spacing, and can't answer my question I'll be dumping here:

Here what I actually did, from [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7299508.html):

```
# vim /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Uncomment:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink
```

As I can understand from [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-912344-start-0.html), things should work normally, but for some reason the daemon doesn't want to play. Still a hack, but things work.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this that was being caused by interference with Jack (jackd) on 13.04.  I never had the issue on 12.10.  I removed Jack and Ardour and all worked perfectly.  `sudo apt-get remove --purge jack ardour jackd`

If you don't have Jack installed, consider any other packages that might be holding your sound card hostage.

Try running `aplay -l` without the `sudo` and see if that helps with your permission error.  Occasionally I've seen root get denied access to folders in a user's home (which to my understanding shouldn't happen, but I've seen it).

Comment: I don't have anything that seems that it'd hijack pulse, but I did some googling and only came up with one thread:
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7299508.html?sid=5a330aff6f7a9d7ccc26da0280629861

Following it directly I got things to work however it seems that it bypassed pulse, I got sound but could only control it from alsamixer, hardware buttons didn't work and the sound widget didn't work. I then removed 'device=', and things worked! ...somewhat, I still get a weird, loud scratch when I boot into lightdm. Still better than nothing, hardware buttons work too.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a permission error. You are running `sudo aplay -l` which should not be necessary. As a user you should be able to run `aplay -l`.

Probably you have to update the ACLs in `/dev/snd/*` (change `username` to your own):

```
sudo setfacl -m u:username:rw /dev/snd/*
```

You won't need to uncomment `load-module module-alsa-sink` in the configuration script. Probably you have done other things that - as side effect changed the permissions - because if you only uncomment that line you would see something like this if you run `pulseaudio -vvv`:

```
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_direct.c: unable to open timer 'hw:CLASS=3,SCLASS=0,CARD=0,DEV=0,SUBDEV=0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_dmix.c: unable to initialize poll_fd
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device default: Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-sink" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

And as you see it shows indeed that there is a permission error.

I hope this helps someone next time with thinking about permission issues before he/she starts to delve deep into the options of `pulseaudio` or `alsa`.  :-)